# Xcode if statement never recognizes Active Compilation Conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, target, compiler-flags

[image]

[image]

As you can see, in my `Active compilation conditions` I have 2 `flags(or whatever it is called)`,  **A** and **B**. 
I have 2 targets, so the first target has flag A, the second target has flag B...

In code, I am trying to define a value depending on selected app target, but problem is that it never enters the `#if` block, but always the `#else` block.

I have been trying to solve this for hours, but nothing helped me. I also tried to put `-D` in my flag name, tried to also define the `A` and `B` in `Other Swift Flags`...
Nothing worked.

This is my simple code:

```
#if A
    #define kId @"a1a2a3" //never executed.
#else
    #define kId @"b1b2b3" //always executed. Weird thing is also that I put a breakpoint here but its never catched...
#endif
```

[image: Apple Clang - Preprocessing]

Comment: Is this for Swift or Objective-C? Have you tried setting `A=1`?

Comment: its objc in the code I put above. A=1? where?

Comment: If you wrote your simple code in the Objective-C part, write the `A=1` the same way you there is `DEBUG=1`.

Comment: Ok @Larme, should I put anything for `B`, perhaps `=2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active Compilation Conditions are for Swift and are analogous to Preprocessor Macros in Objective-C/C/C++.

In C-based languages lines beginning with `#` are preprocessor directives.

Since you are using Objective-C, to use `#if` in your code the value of `A` should be non-zero. If you only want to test whether `A` is defined you may use `#ifdef` instead. Define `A=1` in the `Preprocessor Macros` under `Apple Clang - Preprocessing`.

Comment: I don't understand you well. I have edited my question and attached the image at the bottom where you can see my `Apple Clang - Preprocessing`. Please check it.

Comment: I assume you want to set the conditional for both Debug and Release targets. Double-click the Debug values (`DEBUG=1 COCOAPODS=1`) in `Preprocessor Macros`, click  `+` in the sheet to add a new value, and type `A=1`. Then do the same for the Release configuration.

Comment: Ok @sbooth, should I put anything for `B`, perhaps `=2` ?

Comment: That depends on how your code is structured and what preprocessor directives you're using.